# Chrome Notifications on multiple Tabs

Tags: javascript, notifications

I've added chrome notifications in my web app. If there are multiple tabs open for the same application. It pushes multiple notifications for the same activity.
I resolved this by adding a `tag` field. But now it is flickering, i.e. looks like notifications is overlapping.

Is there any way to show just one notification with no overlapping?

Comment: Also tried by storing NotificationID in local and added check. But sometimes working great and sometimes not due to same duration of execution.